# Element Click Intercepted Exception

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, xpath, automated-tests

I am unable to perform click operation on Sign-in button in my application.

Below is the HTML code.and u can find the exact button element in last line.

```
<div class="form-group dl-padding-10">

                        <select class="form-control form-control-solid" name="SelectedRoleID" id="SelectedRoleID" onchange="removeBorderColor()" required="">
                                <option id="default_val" selected="" disabled="" hidden="">Profile </option>
                                    <option value="15">Service Consultant</option>
                                    <option value="11">DLBO Developer</option>
                                    <option value="16">Admin Agent</option>
                                    <option value="17">Team Leader</option>
                                    <option value="18">Manager</option>
                                    <option value="19">CV Mandator</option>
                                    <option value="20">CV Agent</option>
                                    <option value="21">Forensics Agent</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="dl-align-left" id="show_text" style="color:red">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="circle1-mask form-group" id="FingerprintContent" style="height:140px;z-index:2; background-image: none;">
                        <img src="Assets/img/fingerprint4.gif" id="fingerprint-img" data-status="active" style="height:140px; width:100px;" onclick="DeviceScript.scanFingerPrint(event)">
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group dl-padding-10">
                            <button type="submit" id="register-btn" class="btn btn-block dl-button-primary dl-no-margin">Sign In (For Testing Purpose Only)</button>
                        </div>


                </div>
            </div>
</form>    </div>
</div>
```

Kindly help me with the suitable xpath to perform click operation on the sign-in button.

Also find the image of code tried.[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJeJI.png)

```
Xpath=”//button[contains(text(), 'Sign In (For Testing Purpose Only)')]”
(Or)

IWebElement Signin = driver.FindElement(By.Id("register-btn"));
            Signin.Click();
(Or)

IWebElement Signinbutton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(), 'Sign In (For Testing Purpose Only)')]"));


            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            
            action.MoveToElement(Signinbutton).Click().Perform();
```

```
The error which i get:
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException : element click intercepted: Element <button type="submit" id="register-btn" class="btn btn-block dl-button-primary dl-no-margin">...</button> is not clickable at point (758, 646). Other element would receive the click: <div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">...</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with javascript:

```
IWebElement Signinbutton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(), 'Sign In (For Testing Purpose Only)')]"));
IJavaScriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", Signinbutton );
```

Comment: that's pretty straightforward and works like charm

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing some html since the error references a footer.

Not a fan of thread sleeps but try one and see if the thread sleep allows the page to load. I am wondering if your page is still loading and trying to click. If the sleep works, I would remove that and do a move to element or try a java click.

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(), 'Sign In')]")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("register-btn")).Click();
```

Comment: This is why I wonder about the footer. Based on your html, this all works fine for me. Does your footer have additional links for login where the xpath is finding more than one element?

Comment: No..the footer doesnt have any links for signin..My doubt is on my xpath..since the button tag falls under multiple 'div' does there should be any change in xpath?

Comment: The locator should only return one element and the divs do not matter. Locating by ID is faster than xpath. However being smart with your xpath is also key. While you could use //div[@class='form-group dl-padding-10']/button[@id='register-btn'], it would be better to use the id "register-btn". What you do not want is xpath that is brittle like //div[2]/span[4]/ul/a[3] - these are the worst.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting is because the button you are trying to click is behind this element 
`<div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">...</div>` 
Which seems to be the footer of your page.

You can try any of the following steps to solve the issue

1. Scroll to any element below the sign-in button(If any). You can use the below code for that:

   `protected boolean scrollToElement(WebElement element)
               throws NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException {
           try {
               jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
               return true;
           } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
               logError("Element Not found exception when scrolling to element (JavaScript)", e);
               throw e;
           } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
               logError("Stale element exeption when scrolling to element (JavaScript)", e);
               throw e;
           }
       }`

   2. Close the footer if it is for **accept cookies** or something similar, or you can also apply Custom CSS to that element to hide it and then try to click the element.

   `String css= "display:none !important;"
   protected void addCustomCSS(WebElement webElement, String css) {
               registerCall(new Object() {
               }.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
               try {
                   String style = (String) jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].getAttribute('style')", webElement);
                   jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', " + css + ")", webElement);
                   stylesQueue.add(style);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }`